# Ubuntu Server - RAID1: Operating System not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, raid1

I'm trying a RAID1 on Ubuntu Server 12.04 in virtual machine and I followed the post:
[RAID1: How do I "Fail" a drive that's marked as "removed"?](https://serverfault.com/questions/97565/raid1-how-do-i-fail-a-drive-thats-marked-as-removed)

I added two disks and created the RAID1 and it works.
After I removed the second disk and added a new disk. Copied the fs on the new and RAID works.
But if I remove the first disk, the second will not start.
I've a "Operating System not found"
Someone can help me? Thank you

Comment: Check that the new disk has a valid boot record. (Step 3 in the link you referenced)

Comment: I've an error 17, cannot mount selected partition.
Maybe it's an error of mine.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you using software raid provided by the kernel? If so, be aware that this only mirrors logical constructs on the disk (i.e., a volume) and not the whole disk. Since the bootloader exists outside of the volume that is mirrored, the bootloader is not mirrored for you.

If you are expecting to boot off of either drive, then you must take extra steps to make sure you have your boot loader (i.e., GRUB or whatever you are using) installed properly on both drives.

Comment: thanks for the answer.
First to remove the disk, I checked them with fdisk -l /dev/sda and fdisk -l /dev/sdb and they are equal, as partitions and boot (*)
Do you mean this?

Comment: I've two disks with two partitions,both Primary. One for swap and the other for /

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to check.

In your BIOS, Check the HDD Boot Priority (if available.)
This is not the boot device order.
If you have multiple HDDs in you Computer, you can select the primary HDD to boot from.

[image: Image taken from the EP-45-DS4P Manual]

Comment: I'm on vmware but I just checked it. Thank you